# AndroidVolley: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response); causes exception

Tags: php, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

please I need some help. Whenever I implement:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

it causes my code to jump to the exception block.

I am using the php method:

```
echo json_encode(array("code"=>$code));
```

to pass the JSON string to my application. The raw response string I get is:

```
{"code":"UserIsValid"}
```

I looked at the documentation and it says that `JSONArray(String json)` is a valid way to initialize the JSON Array. I am using Volley to communicate with my database, which seems to work well. My relevant application code looks like this:

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error response
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Server file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", user_name);
                return params;
            }
        };
        //Adds post request to request queue using MySingleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

I am very glad for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sending JSONObject as response from your PHP, you have to use JSONObject class for parsing string to JSON. Try the following

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, jsonObject.getString("code"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error response
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Server file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", user_name);
                return params;
            }
        };
        //Adds post request to request queue using MySingleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

When you encode multidimensional array in PHP, the result will be in the format of JSONArray, otherwise it will be encoded as JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's `Json Object`. You should try to use `JSONObject` instead as:

```
 try {
           JSONObject jsonArray = new JSONObject(response);
           Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   } catch (JSONException e) {
   }
```